# Weird asset encoding on Android 4.x WebView (android + phonegap case)

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview

I'm working with android + phonegap + jquerymobile bundle on my project and I stumbled on a problem with asset encoding in WebView in different Android versions. I've posted bug to Apache Cordova (aka Phonegap) bugtracker https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-811 (there are bug description and examples). They answered that it must be android bug. I've issued the bug on android 4.0 and waited that version 4.1 will fix it, but now customers report that 4.1 is broken either. Please help me find workaround to get my apps work on both 2.x and 4.x versions (maybe there is some settings that must be applied to WebView). Thank you in advance.